# Copying different ranges of cell data from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I need to be able to copy different ranges of cells from one worksheet to another. For example A1:A4, C3:C7, D3:D6. I need the code to do the following:

- Copy different data from those cells in the first worksheet (worksheet1) and paste them onto the same line but transposed on the second worksheet (worksheet2). I don't need to keep the original formatting.
- When pasting the data I need it to find the last row and paste it below that row.

I can write a code which will do most of that but I only know how to get the code to do it for one cell range e.g. A1:A4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where will the ranges you want to copy be stored/derrived from?  Can you show the code you have also

Comment: Write the code you know how to write. We'll show you how to make it repetitive.

Comment: Would you like to paste all transposed (column) ranges on the same row of worksheet2? Do you have a logic to be applied in order to set the ranges to be copied (A1:A4, C3:C7, D3:D6)?

Comment: Sub Draft()

Worksheets("Material Check").Range("B3:B6").Copy
Worksheets("Archive").Range("A2:D2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub

Comment: The range will obviously increase on worksheet 2 to whatever it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

OK, technically SO isn't a code-writing service but I use a code that does basically just that, so you might as well have it;

```
Sub CopyTransposeRange()

Dim shtCopy As Worksheet
Dim shtPaste As Worksheet
Dim rngCopy As Range

Set shtCopy = Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set shtPaste = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set rngCopy = Range("A1:A36")
'Put whatever's necessary in here to select the correct range

shtCopy.rngCopy.Copy
shtPaste.Activate
shtPaste.Range(Cells(shtPaste.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1), Cells(shtPaste.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, rngCopy.Rows.Count)).PasteSpecial _
xlPasteAll, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, True

End Sub
```

Yes, I know activating sheets isn't best practice, but works for me  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

hope it helps.

Comment: I'll give that a go. Thank you!

Comment: If you change `Set rngCopy = Range("A1:A36")` to `Set rngCopy = shtCopy.Range("A1:A36")` then there's no need to `Activate` and is generally consider much 'safer'.

Comment: @CLR Thanks for that, that's the bit I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, please.

It will copy your selected range and transpose it in the roe 2 of second sheet:

```
Sub testCopyTransposedRanges()
  Dim sh2 As Worksheet, inpRng As Range, lastCol As Long, arrTr As Variant

  Set inpRng = Application.InputBox("Select range to be copied and transposed:", _
                                    "Range Selection", Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    If inpRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    arrTr = inpRng.value
    If IsEmpty(arrTr) Then Exit Sub
    Set sh2 = Worksheets("worksheet2") ' use here your sheet name!!!
    lastCol = sh2.Cells(2, Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    sh2.Cells(2, lastCol).Resize(, UBound(arrTr)).value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrTr)
End Sub
```

It must be 'filterred' for 'Cancel', multi column selection etc. But this will be done only if such a solution matches your need. Otherwise, you must present the logic based on what to create an algorithm to automatically select the necessary ranges.